# Exclude records with only one attribute

Tags: sql-server

I have a bunch of records within a table with multiple attributes attached to it. I would like to only exclude individuals who have ONLY purchased.

Here is a table of how it would look:

```
ID | Bought | Paid | Smiled | Bag

1 | Yes | Yes | Yes | No

2 | Yes | No | Yes | Yes

3 | Yes | No | No | No

4 | No | No | No | No

5 | Yes | No | Yes | No
```

What is the general format for only returning records 1, 2, 4, 5 in a WHERE statement, **keeping in mind that I want to avoid querying each attribute in a WHERE statement because there are hundreds.**

Comment: Why are you expecting record 4?

Comment: Can you explain why you only expect records 1, 2, 4 and 5 to be returned?

Comment: Do you mean you want only records where `Bought = 'Yes'` and all other columns are 'No'? If so then please **[edit]** the question to say so.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to specify or unpivot hundreds of columns, consider the following

The following will dynamically UNPIVOT your data without actually having to use Dynamic SQL.

I should add that NULL values would NOT excluded.  In this case they would be considered a distinct value.

**Example**

```
Select A.ID
      ,Value = min(C.Value)
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW,ELEMENTS XSINIL) as xml))) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select Item  = a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                      ,Value = a.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                 From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row')  as C1(n)
                 Cross Apply C1.n.nodes('./*') as C2(a)
                 Where a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('ID','OtherColumns','ToExclude')
             ) C
 Group By ID
 Having min(Value)=max(Value)
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Value
4   No
```